# Microsoft Graph API - Authorization_IdentityNotFound Error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am able to call the following API and get an access token:
POST [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)

However, I get the an error whenever calling the following API using the access token:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

{
"error": {
"code": "Authorization_IdentityNotFound",
"message": "The identity of the calling application could not be established."
}
}

Any idea what I am missing in my app configuration that's causing this error? Thanks!

I have the following API permissions enabled:

- Application.Read.All (Application)
- Directory.Read.All (Application)
- Directory.ReadWrite.All (Application)
- User.Read.All (Application)
- User.ReadWrite.All (Application)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I created an Azure AD Application and added API permissions:

[image]

Now, I generated  **access token**  using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

When I decoded the token, scope is present like below:

[image]

Now, using the above generated token  **I am able to fetch the users**  successfully:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
```

[image]

The error  ***"Authorization_IdentityNotFound message: The identity of the calling application could not be established"***  usually occurs due to invalid access token, incorrect app configuration, or insufficient permissions.

To resolve the error, check the below:

- Check if the access token is not expired.
- Verify that the access token’s app ID and tenant ID match those from the app’s Azure AD registration.
- Verify that the app registration has the appropriate API permissions, and that admin consent is done.
- Check the access token has the scopes required to call the Microsoft Graph API.
- Check to see if any conditional access that might be preventing access to the Microsoft Graph API.